# How to Get Text Overlay on Images in WordPress?

Tags: image, wordpress, slideshow

I want to have some text overlay on Images and am using WordPress.

See this site - http://www.gxigroup.com

On the site, in Center, you can see an Image whose description is hid just LEFT side. When the "Show Text" button is clicked, the text comes up on the Image.

My questions is, How can I get the same functionality on my website running WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding some javascript to your header.php template file.  Start with these and you should be able to get it.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/javascript-slider

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done with jQuery. I recommend you to search on Google "jquery slide panel examples", theres millions of plugins that do the effect you want.

Some of them:

- http://web-kreation.com/demos/Sliding_login_panel_jquery/#
- http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/jquery/simple-slide-panel.html
- http://web-kreation.com/demos/login_panel_mooslide/